# Codeigniter : how to change path for session

Tags: codeigniter, session

How I can change current path from `/~shinobu22/ci` into `/`? I have problem about session lose after redirect or change page.

[image: current path]

So, I think it's happen from my URL `/~shinobu22/` (I didn't create this name MAC OS create from my username).

Comment: Its already in root. `/~shinobu22/` pc name and `ci` is project name

Comment: @Abdulla thx for you advance. but, i suspect why it not / ? and a little bit more it will generate new ci_session name in every page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `application/config/config.php` file for the cookie path:

```
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
```

Another option is to allow it site-wide:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".example.com";
```